# OkHttp Client returns a null value

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm trying to use okhttpclient with okhttp3, but it return a null value.

This is my code :

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("http://www.test.com/get_data.php").newBuilder();
urlBuilder.addEncodedQueryParameter("GroupName", groupName);
String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        try {
            String responseData = response.body().string();
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseData);
            jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
    }
});
```

then responseData returns {"result":[]}

I try with the same url above but with different method with httpClient, it returns the value I want, here is the httpclient code :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.test.com/get_data.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
HttpResponse response   = httpclient.execute(httppost);
Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String result = null;
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()), 65728);
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }

    if(sb.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
        result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Please help me, someone who have experience with okhttp, why i need okhttp ?
Because httpClient is already deprecated in sdk 23, thanks.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/03/10/random-musings-android-5p1-sdk.html

Comment: it seems you are getting a response from your server, so if there is a problem with the content of the response, it is with your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not executing on the client object. Try adding the following code snippet:

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
```

In order to refer to an example, please see the following link: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html

Comment: `execute()` runs it synchronously, `enqueue()` runs it asynchronously.

Comment: i solved my problem, actually it's because the okhttp using GET method while i'm using POST, but now your answer be my problem when i use client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() i cant get the value, but if im using execute() like your answer, i can get the value, so what should i do? i need to know when i get failure